# Webhook failing in rabbtimq

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubectl

I have install rabbitmq cluster using rabbitmq cluster operator. I have also added rabbitmq topology operator. I am trying to create queues using rabbitmq topology operator using following yml file

```
kind: Queue
metadata:
name: software-results
namespace: rabbitmq-system
spec:
name: software-results # name of the queue
type: quorum # without providing a queue type, rabbitmq creates a classic queue
autoDelete: false
durable: true # seting 'durable' to false means this queue won't survive a server restart
rabbitmqClusterReference:
  name: client-queues
```

I am getting error as

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "singleQueue.yml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "vqueue.kb.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://webhook-service.rabbitmq-system.svc:443/validate-rabbitmq-com-v1beta1-queue?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.97.65.156:443: connect: connection refused
```

I tried to search for the same but didn't find much. Can anyone help me what exactly is going wrong here ?